# What am I doing wrong in sampling my shadowMap?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using RenderDoc to verify that my shadowMap is being created properly and it has the correct pixels from the lights point of view.

It's just depth. And I can see the shadows have a depth of 0 and the rest has a depth of 1.

I'm passing my Lights MVP Matrix to my shader as well as this ShadowMap:

My vertex shader:
    #version 400

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

uniform mat4 lightMVP;

out vec4 ex_positionLightSpace;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_position;
    ex_positionLightSpace = lightMVP * in_position;
}
```

and here's my frag shader:

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec4 ex_positionLightSpace;

uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

float CalcShadowFactor(sampler2D shadowMapp, vec4 lightSpacePos)
{
    vec3 projectedCoords = lightSpacePos.xyz / lightSpacePos.w;
    vec2 coords;
    coords.x = 0.5 * projectedCoords.x + 0.5;
    coords.y = 0.5 * projectedCoords.y + 0.5;
    float z = 0.5 * projectedCoords.z + 0.5;
    float depth = texture(shadowMapp,coords).x;
    if(depth < z + 0.00001)
        return 0.2;
    return 1.0;
}

void main(void)
{
    float shadowFactor = CalcShadowFactor(shadowMap,ex_positionLightSpace);
    color = vec4(shadowFactor,shadowFactor,shadowFactor,1.0);
}
```

I've simplified my shaders so that all I want to see is either a very dim pixel or a very bright pixel. But all I'm getting is the very dim pixel.

I've checked that it's definitely the same Light MVP that was used to generate the shadowmap.

Edit: The issue turned out to be an incorrect LightMVP. I wasn't sending through the model matrix of the object, just the lights view and projection. Lesson learned.

Comment: Check again dude, the main function passes the correct shadowmap uniform through the function parameter. I know my naming convention is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried sampler2DShadow? Usage is pretty simple:

```
uniform sampler2DShadow depthTexture; //does the depth comparison for you
//other uniforms
vec4 coord = shadowCoord / shadowCoord.w; //perspective division or use function textureProj() which does perspective division for you
float shadow = texture(depthTexture, vec3(coord.xyz));
//some other code, lighting etc.
```

Or are you limited to use only sampler2D?

Edit: You need to set  GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC  Parameter and texture type must be GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 (24/32).

Comment: Yes thanks. I've sinced found the issue with my code and implemented pcf shadows as well (using sampler2dshadow)